# Why does Create React App .env for api keys doesn't work when uploaded to AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I added a dotenv file for an api key in my react app, i followed this tutorial: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/hiding-secret-keys-in-create-react-app as well as this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ I prefixed it as REACT_APP_API_KEY. The app works locally but not when uploaded to AWS.

This the on load fetch:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie/?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=all`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        setMovieList(data.results);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

This the search submit button handler:

```
const handleSearch = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie/?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const jsondata = await response.json();
      await setMovies(jsondata.results);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, [query]);
```

Here's the local working app:
[image]

Here's the App uploaded in AWS
[image]

Comment: The doc you linked says "WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!", and that seems like exactly what you're doing here...

Comment: Either way, what exactly have you uploaded to AWS? (Also, which AWS service have you uploaded it to?)

Comment: @AKX yeah i know cause it's working locally, what i meant is how do make it work in production, how do i hide the api key and make it work in production?

Comment: If you need to use a service that requires a secret API key, you will need to proxy your requests through some non-client service that provides the secret.

Comment: @AKX I'm using the AWS-Amplify for the simple React app. I'm using the themoviedb.org api

Comment: I've never used Amplify, so I can't help you there. I did add that detail to the title and tags though. Good luck

Comment: You probably ran `yarn build` right and then uploaded the `build` directory.  There is no actual process binary that you run (from React's perspective) after that.  It's all handled by some other server that it is oblivious to.  Any variables that did exist are hard-injected into the built app at build time https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html

Answer (score 0):

Typically, whenever you deploy a React app created with *Create React App* (CRA), you run `yarn build` and then upload the `build` directory to some hosting solution.  There is no actual process binary that you run (from React's perspective) after that.

During development, CRA's toolchain (Webpack dev server) is a running process and handles the actual serving and building of content which means it has access to the variables from `.env`.  Once you have run `yarn build`, CRA is hands off and all the execution is handled by some other server that CRA is oblivious to.  Any variables that **did** exist are hard-injected into the built app at build time [Referencing Environment Variables in the HTML](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html).

If you need these variables to change based on a deployment, you should have another `.env` file that gets used in your build tools or make them regular environment variables available in your build script.  Just about every continuous deployment (CI) tool has this capability.

Comment: I did create a .env file but it was added into the gitignore as instructed in the tutorial links. When uploading to AWS through github, it automatically processed the build.

Comment: I have the same issue. I've added the API Key in Amplify's Environment variables, but the api key does not load during the build process